# Devexpress TableView using button with command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have a Devexpress GridControl with a Tableview as it's View.
Underneath that GridControl I have a button with a command & CommandParameter (which links to the Tableview's name.)

The problem I have is that my command gets called, but the tableview isn't in the parameter... (sender is always null)

Does anybody else seem to have this problem before?

I have the same problem when I want to bind the commandparameter to the GridControl (gvOverview)

He is my wpf example:

```
    <dxg:GridControl Name="gvOverview" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" dxg:GridBorderHelper.ShowBorder="False" SelectionMode="Row">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CatA"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CatB"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CatC"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CatD"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowHorizontalScrollingVirtualization="True" AutoWidth="False" ShowSearchPanelMode="Always" helpers:DoubleClickRowHelper.DataGridDoubleClickCommand="{Binding DetailCommand}"  BorderThickness="0" NavigationStyle="Row" AllowCascadeUpdate="False" x:Name="tableViewName" ShowTotalSummary="False" AllowEditing="False" BestFitMode="AllRows" ShowGroupPanel="False" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
    <Button Name="btnExport" Command="{Binding ExportWagonListCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tableViewName}" />
```

c#:

```
  private void ExportList(TableView sender)
    {
       //sender = null...
    }
```

Edit:

I ran Snoop to see if the GridControl / Tableview are actualy in the visualtree. (Do not mind the names, they have been adjusted to my needs.
They are. See image:
[image: Snoop image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you noticed that the name of the TableView is `x:Name="tableViewName"`?

Comment: Yeah I did sorry, this was just for example purpose, I placed it wrong here, it's correct in my code sorry ;) (Changed it)